# How to return only only specified Key's value from dictionary using TryGetValue() method

Tags: c#, json, api, dictionary, serialization

I am trying to get my method to return a matchKey's value as I pass this to the method but the value is returning as Null. Also it shows my dictionary contains the Key and the value i am looking for also my if(Items.TryGetValue(item.Key.Contains(matchKey).ToString() returns true but it does not  add it to the second dictionary I have..  My Items dictionary has all the key and values and I am able to return that.. but I am trying to extract one of the key which is "id" and its value "80" from that and adding to my second dictionary keyValues and returning that if it contains..

```
Here is the Json after Serializing 
{"UserId":"","UserId2":"","id":"80"}
```

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetKeyAndValues(string matchKey)
{
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataEntries);
    Dictionary<string, string> Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
    Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in Items)
    {
        if (!Items.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        {
            Items.Add(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
        }
        var value = Items[matchKey];
        if(Items.TryGetValue(item.Key.Contains(matchKey).ToString(), out value))
        {
            keyValues.Add(matchKey, value);
            return keyValues;
        }
    }

    return Items;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I see several problems in your code, and I would like to ask you some questions to make your code clearer to me. What is `dataEntries`? Why don't you simply get required value directly from it? Why do you serialize it into `JSON`, then convert this `JSON` to `Dictionary<string, string>` and then get required value from it?

Comment: Hi :), the dataEntries is a class where I am holding the properties or the Keys of the Json.. UserId, UserID2 and id. The reason why I am serializing the json is so I can then Deserialize it in a dictionary. I need the dictionary because I am performing some HTTP call to the service and passing my query parameters as a Dictionary key/pair value.

Comment: Does method `GetKeyAndValues` have to return a `Dictionary` with a single `KeyValuePair`? Or can it return a `KeyValuePair` instead of `Dictionary`? Do you consider using `Reflection` to find required value by its key, instead of using current algorithm `ToJson -> ToDictionary -> FindValue`?

Comment: The approach that can be used is the following. Using `Reflection` find required property by `matchKey` and get its value. Then create `Dictionary` with a single `KeyValuePair` and return it.

Comment: Yes it has to return a Dictionary due to applying this Dictionary as my queryParameter, becuase my queryParameter accepts a Dictionary.  Can you show a sample of the usage of this Reflection in this way please..

Comment: I noticed that method `GetKeyAndValues` returns `Items` if a key `matchKey` is not found. Therefore your current approach is better than `Reflection`. I posted an answer how to fix your current method.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem in your code is in this line of code:

```
if (Items.TryGetValue(item.Key.Contains(matchKey).ToString(), out value))
```

It doesn't check if an item with the key `matchKey` is contained in the `Items` dictionary. This sub-expression `item.Key.Contains(matchKey)` checks if `matchKey` is contained in the `Items` and returns `true` or `false`. Therefore this problem line checks if a key with value `true` of `false` is contained in the `Items`.

Here is a fixed method `GetKeyAndValues`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetKeyAndValues(string matchKey)
{
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataEntries);
    Dictionary<string, string> Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);

    // We don't need a loop to check if a key "matchKey" is contained in the "Items".
    // Items.TryGetValue(matchKey, out string value) checks if "matchKey" is contained
    // in the "Items", and if it is contained it returns an appropriate "value".
    if (Items.TryGetValue(matchKey, out string value))
    {
        // Here we create a Dictionary with a single pair (matchKey, value).
        return new Dictionary<string, string> {{matchKey, value}};
    }

    return Items;
}
```

Here is a useful link to the documentation of the method [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Please, check mark my answer as a correct if it helped you and solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes I did but since I am new here it prompts me this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @JamesOein [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time).